# New Window or New Tab -- Way to decide?

Tags: html, hyperlink, target

On a link, is there a way to specify whether the new _blank window is actually a new window or a new tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no garuanteed way to do this.  You can, however, specify height and width for you new window.  Doing this will force the link to open in a new window, and not a tab in most browsers.

```
window.open(url, windowName, height=400, width=400);
```

I would caution against doing this, however.  Tabs vs. windows is a user preference for a reason.

Comment: which browsers open window.open in a new tab?

Comment: +1  In most cases, it is best to let the user decide.  @Pasta, in Firefox 3.5.6 you can set it under Tools>Options>Tabs>option:"Open new windows in a new tab instead"

Comment: Chrome also does so by default.  I would speculatively say most browsers are heading in this direction.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing yet, but when new browsers support CSS3 we will have the ability to tab link. Take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target0

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not (at least not in the current HTML specifications...).

And actually, why would you *want* to? The user probably has set his/her browser to open either in tabs or windows depending on *what the user prefers*. Overriding user preferences will just piss them off :P

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.